# Struct not compiling?

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to learn structs and have the following code below in the .h and .c files respectively.

```
    typedef struct{
    int lengthOfSong;
    int yearRecorded;
} Song;

Song makeSong (int length, int year);
void displaySong(Song theSong);
```

.c:

```
Song makeSong(int length, int year){
    Song newSong;
    newSong.lengthOfSong = length;
    newSong.yearRecorded = year;

    displaySong(newSong);

    return newSong;
}

void displaySong(Song theSong){
    printf("This is the length of the song: %i \n This is the year recorded: %i", theSong.lengthOfSong, theSong.yearRecorded);
}
```

For some reason i'm getting the error: song.c:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘makeSong’
song.c:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘theSong’

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit main (the other functions were already working):

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include "math_functions.h"
#include "song.h"

main(){
    int differ = difference(10, 5);
    int thesum = sum(3, 7);
    printf("differnece: %i, sum: %i \n", differ, thesum);
    Song theSong = makeSong(5, 8);

}
```

Comment: yes. see the main above. (edited)

Comment: Did you `#include "song.h"` in the .c file which contains `Song makeSong(int length, int year){`? Looks like not, as the cited line is the 1st, according to the compiler error message.

Comment: I don't think you need to do add the #include in the actual .c file...I could be wrong though, I'm new to this.

Comment: @cfarm54: You do. There's no behind-the-scenes magic related to filenames in C, you have to explicitly include header files that contain the definitions (in this case Song) that you need in a .c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`displaySong` takes an argument **theSong** and you're trying to use **newSong**

You'll also need to `#include "song.h"` from `song.c` - the error message looks like you skipped that.

Comment: As a side note, please use `Song song`, not `Song theSong`. Articles in code are _so_ ugly.

Comment: Note that the compiler reports error already at line 1. BTW this proves that that .c file contains no #include :)

Comment: Although this is true, it's not the problem. I fixed that and I still get the same issue.

Comment: @cfarm54: could you please post the updated code and exact error message?

Comment: @cfarm54: You still haven't included song.h from song.c

Comment: @erik what do you mean? I have #include "song.h" in my main right? is there somewhere else that I need to put this #include?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `#include "song.h"` in the .c file where `makeSong()` and `displaySong()` are defined. Otherwise the compiler does not know how to create objects of type `Song`.

Comment: @cfarm54: Not above main. You also need the include above `Song makeSong(int length, int year){`. You need the include in **ALL** .c files.

Comment: i think a lot of people are saying this but i'm a bit confused as to where i need to put the #include maybe. it seems like I have it in the right place in my main.c but maybe I need to put it somewhere else too?

Comment: @cfarm54: First line of `song.c` should be `#include "song.h"`

Comment: Yes @cfarm54. You need the `#include "song.h"` at the top of **EVERY .c FILE** that refers in any way to the type `Song`.

Answer (score 1):

With the earlier corrections made, still you are getting error because program is not including `song.h` in both the header files. Source files need to include `song.h` ( i.e., in `main.c` and `song.c`, guessing you have named source files like that ). Also -

```
Song makeSong(int length, int year){
    Song newSong;
    newSong.lengthOfSong = length;
    newSong.yearRecorded = year;

    displaySong(newSong);

    return newSong;
}
```

can be simplified to -

```
Song makeSong(int length, int year){

    Song newSong = { length, year } ;

    displaySong(newSong);

    return newSong;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Messed `typedef` in my previous answer:

```
typedef struct NAME1 {
    ...
} NAME2;
```

`NAME1` names the struct, `NAME2` the explizit type `struct NAME1`.
Now `NAME1` can't be used without `struct` in C, `NAME2` can:

```
struct NAME1 myvar1;
NAME2 myvar2;
```

You're getting the issue cause `Song` isn't recognizes as a variable type (without the `struct` keyword before).

Comment: Yes, messed the typedef, should be fixed now.